# Sending callback function from Client to Server in Socket.io

Tags: socket.io

I want my client to react to an event on server side, I wonder if it is possible to send a callback function from client to server using `socket.io` , and call it on server side whenever that server-side event happens. Does it work this way and does the client-side function reacts to that call ?

Comment: this is client-server communication. When an event is caught server side, then you can do whatever you want (call a function with callback...) AND in your function code, you can send something to the client... Without code/example we cannot really help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't send a callback from client to server.

Instead, using socket.io, you can send a message (with some optional data) from client to server or from server to client.  If the receiving end has a listener for that particular message name, then its listener will get called and any data that was sent with the message will be available to that listener.

You can see examples of using `.emit()` to send messages and using `.on("someMsg", fn)` to receive messages [here in the socket.io doc](http://socket.io/docs/#sending-and-receiving-events).

You do not generally send code from client to server or vice versa.  While it is technically possible, it is generally not done that way for a number of reasons.  Instead, you include the code ahead of time in each client and server for the behaviors you wish to support and then you use the messages and data that are sent from client to server or vice versa to trigger the desired code to run.